# Entitlement unread for configure iCloud with two applications

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, icloud, entitlements

I try to use one iCloud container for my two applications. 
My problem is, it won't read my entitlement file. No matter what iCloud container I specify it won't read it. Instead it uses the default one in the provisioning profile... 
I don't even need to enable entitlement in target settings to use the default container which is the same name than my app id.

But of course, if I want to use one iCloud container for two applications, I need to specify in at least one application a different iCloud container in order to get this things working.

I tried with a all new project, and of course it works. I can specify anything in the entitlements, and I'll have a valid iCloud URL.

What can I do? I delete the entitlement, re-add it at least a thousand times... I don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: I solve the issue ! I went to the target build settings, then Code Signing Identity. The name of the Entitlement file wasn't fill in the "Any iOS SDK" settings, it was just for the configuration Debug, Release, etc... :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try opening the default entitlements file in a text editor and add the required container url keys in there?

Comment: The good container url is already in my entitlement file... I don't think this is coming from the entitlement configuration. I think that Xcode doesn't read my entitlement file, otherwise I'll have the good iCloud URL instead of the default one, right?